# Importing Office 2013 type library, Delphi XE3

Tags: delphi, ms-office, delphi-xe3

I have Office 2013 and RAD Studio XE3 installed. When trying to import the Excel, Word, and Outlook type libraries using the Delphi Wizard the type libaries are no longer listed. How can I create the type libraries?

Comment: you can use the import units that ship with delphi

Comment: but they are Office 2010 maximum

Comment: is Office x86 or x64 ?   "the type libaries are no longer listed"

Comment: the Office 2010 units won't compile because System.Variants.EmptyParam refers to the System interface of the tlb unit and not to System.Variants

Comment: @JoeMeyer are you sure ? but there is no identifier System.Variants in system unit. And using "Variants.EmptyParam" would require "uses Variants" thus discriminating against fully qualified unit names.

Comment: I wonder if 32-bit Delphi IDE can co-operate with 64-bit DLLs of Office then

Comment: @Arioch'The It's out of proc, so there are no problems at all. All combinations of 32/64 bit client with 32/64 bit server work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the import units that ship with Delphi. They work perfectly well with Office 2013. Obviously if you are using interfaces introduced in Office 2013 then they will be missing. But there's no indication that is the case.

These import units are installed in `OCX\Servers`.

Because the Office COM servers run out-of-proc, there are no issues with mixing 32 and 64 bit code.